Failed to reduce the DAE index in Modelica ClaRa+ library
Right now, I'm currently trying to integrate a gas turbine subsystem into a steam power plant example built in the ClaRa+ library. The gas turbine subsystem runs without no problem when ran as a standalone, but when I connect the flue gas outlet to the heat exchanger, the system fails to reduce the DAE index.
Failed to differentiate the equation
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.T = TSMedia.Internals.GasObjectFunctions.temperature_phxi (
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.p, 
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.h, 
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.xi, 
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.gasPointer);

in order to reduce the DAE index.

Cannot find differentiation function:
TSMedia.Internals.GasObjectFunctions.temperature_phxi(
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.p, 
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.h, 
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.xi, 
hEXvle2gas_L3_1ph_BU_simple.shell.bulk.gasPointer)
with respect to time

Failed to reduce the DAE index.

Model file (requires ClaRa+ library to be installed) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/17hmqHfhDOzIIyWOiHOq-EMbNEQKYrV2h/view?usp=sharing
From what I've learned from other problems regarding DAE index reducing such as this or this other one, it involves modifying the equation in some way, which I'm doubtful of since I'd assume this to be a well-built library. I also tried to give the heat exchanger some initialization (changing the initial pressure, initial shell temperature, initial mass flow), but to no avail since it still pops out the DAE error message, and I'm quite stumped on how to solve it. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

It would be good to see what the model looks like. My guess is that adding volumes to the model at the correct locations will get rid of this issue.

Upgrading solves the issue, tested for:

ClaRaPlus 1.7.1 and Dymola 2023x Refresh 1
ClaRaPlus 1.7.2 and Dymola 2024x
ClaRaPlus 1.7.4 and Dymola 2024x Refresh 1, but set Advanced.Translation.SupportNonLiteralAttributes = false; to avoid some weird warnings.

It seems the library was improved in some way (compared to ClaRaPlus 1.6.0 on the google drive).

Would you mind sharing the exported results?
